# Google Colab: How to set initializing cells

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm new in Google Colab. Whenever I open a Google Colab notebook that I have already been working on, I have to run certain cells to continue my work. In Jupyter Notebooks there is an nbextension that allows me to initialize specific cells that I want to run when I open the notebook. Is there something similar in Google Colab?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue?